# How to place this form that repeats through a partial multiple times in one show view in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, partials

So the problem is this: I have one show view of a parent object (A). This parent has got multiple children (B) which show - through a partial - right under the parent. Then this child has children again (C), showing again under it's parent. All in one view!

I have one form for creating the B's which is right under A and this works fine.
Now the question is, how do I make a form for creating the C's under each B?

To clarify a typical website should look like this:

**A**
**B**
**C**
[Form for *creating* a C]
**B**
**C**
**C**
[Form for *creating* a C]
**B**
[Form for *creating* a C]
[Form for *creating* a B]

With:

**routes.rb**

```ruby
resources :a do
  resources :b do 
    resources :c do
    end
  end
end
```

Then how I got the form for the B to work is with the following controllers:

**as_controller.rb**

```ruby
def show
    @a = A.find(params[:id])
    ## create a blank B
    @b = B.new
    @b.a_id = @a.id 
    ## and for C which doesn't work (yet)
    @c = C.new
    @c.b_id = @b.id
end
```

**bs_controller**

```ruby
def create
  @b = B.new(b_params)
  ## assignment A id
  @b.a_id = params[:a_id] 
  ##
  @b.save
  redirect_to a_path(@b.a)
end
```

But when I do the same for C Rails keeps on saying it can't find the id of B, as so:

**ActionController::UrlGenerationError in As#show**

**No route matches {:action=>"index", :a_id=>"12", :controller=>"cs", :b_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:b_id]**

While I do something similar. Only this time the same should happen each time the _b.html.haml renders the 'c/form'. Which looks like this, but is the only element of my page that doesn't work:

```haml
%h5 ADD C

= form_for [ @a, @b, @c ] do |f|
    %p
    = f.label :c1
    %br
    = f.text_field :c1
    %p
    = f.label :c2
    %br
    = f.text_area :c2
    %p
    = f.submit 'Submit'
```

So again, how do I make this form for C on the partial B showing up multiple times all in this one show page of A right?

Comment: Just notice, in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html says that: "Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep."

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a really hard time following your example.  Are you just asking how to build associations with a nested form?  If so http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: When do you get the error?  When you hit submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message does a pretty good job of highlighting what's going wrong:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in As#show

No route matches {:action=>"index", :a_id=>"12", :controller=>"cs", :b_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:b_id]
```

That's because your As Controller...

```
def show
    ...
    ## create a blank B
    @b = B.new
    @b.a_id = @a.id 
    ...
end
```

Is creating a **new** B for your form, which since it's new doesn't have an ID. When you generate the C form, it has to have an already-existing B to refer to when generating the proper URL for the form, so you have something like:

```
<%= form_for [ existing-a, existing-b, brand-new-c ] do |f| %>
```

However, you can't define the existing-b in the controller since you have an indeterminate number of existing-b's. You'll need to loop through your B's and use a block variable in the form.

**as_controller.rb**

```
def show
    @a = A.find(params[:id])
end
```

**A.html.erb**

```
# Show info about the one A picked in the controller
<%= @a.name %>

# Loop through all of the A's indeterminate number of B's
<% a.bs.each do |b| %>
    <%= b.name %>

    # Show all of the current B's indeterminate number of C's
    <% b.cs.each do |c| %>
        <%= c.name %>
    <% end %>

    # One C form for the controller-selected A, the currently-looped-to B, and a brand-new C.
    <%= form_for [@a, b, C.new] do |f| %>
        #form fields...
    <% end %>
<% end %>

# One B form for the controller-selected A, and a brand-new B.
<%= form_for [@a, B.new] do |f| %>
    #form fields...
<% end %>
```

I know my template is in ERB instead of HAML. Apologies. :)

Comment: Thank you so much! This works. Compliments as well on your explanation: very straightforward and what you came up with is logical and very elegant.

Comment: That's great news! Glad I could help! :)